# No SPIFFS only OTA in NodeMCU ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU ESP8266  ESP-12E and I tried uploading a file thru the SPIFFS.  I am not sure why I see OTA instead of the SPIFFS?

[image: No SPIFFS Only OTA]

Is there a configuration that I missed?

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/Using-ESP8266-SPIFFS/?amp_page=true not sure but check this . It may not help

Comment: maximum application size is less then 1 MB. so there is no other use for the rest of the flash then FS. for board you selected there is no predefined partitioning without OTA. what is your question?

Comment: In this link https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FST/OP12/IZT6TEBJ/FSTOP12IZT6TEBJ.png?auto=webp&frame=1&width=1024&fit=bounds&md=f16daccb8697a6bd8728838feb18d9de it is showing SPIFFS but in my Arduino IDE it is showing OTA?  Why is this so? That is my question

Comment: Yes please refer to my answer and that is because he is using an older version of the package and arduino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPIFFS (SPI Flash File System)  is also know as FS(File system) . so What you are seeing as FS is basically SPIFFS .The OTA partition on esp8266 is compulsory so you cant get rid of it .

Hope this helps

Comment: Ohh Okay so that is how it is.. Thank you then!

Comment: and why is there in Tools menu FS and not SPIFFS as n the mentioned instructable?

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you are asking

Comment: the question was that the menu doesn't  show SPIFFS but FS and OTA. a good answer should contain why it is so.